# Expected / got ; error when sending SES emails with attachments

Tags: phpmailer, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

When sending SES emails with PHP, regardless of whether I use an SMTP endpoint or the AWS SDK, I receive a similar error when sending raw emails with attachments.  Similar errors have been reported in the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147662) and a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/delivery-failures-and-im-baffled/).   When I omit attachments, the emails send without a problem every time.

Via SMTP I receive the following error:

```
554 Transaction failed: Expected '/', got null
```

When using the SDK (`"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.178"`) I receive the following:

```
exception 'Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException' with message 'Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
 <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
   <Error>
     <Type>Sender</Type>
     <Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
  InvalidParameterValue (client): Expected '/', got ; - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
   <Error>
     <Type>Sender</Type>
     <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
     <Message>Expected '/', got ;</Message>
   </Error>
   <RequestId>abc123-abc1-abc1-abc1-abc123acb123</RequestId>
 </ErrorResponse>
```

I am using PHPMailer to send the message:

```php
// Prepare mime message
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setFrom($user['email'], $user['full_name']);
$mail->addAddress($recipient);
$mail->Subject = $entity['title'];
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $entity['body'];
$mail->addStringAttachment(
    'My DOMPDF content',
    'attachment.pdf',
    PHPMailer::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'pdf'
);
$mail->preSend();
$raw = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();

// Prepare SES client
$ses = new SesClient([
    'version' => '',
    'region' => 'eu-west-2'
]);

// Send email
$ses->sendRawEmail([
    'RawMessage' => [
        'Data' => $raw,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should have been using `application/pdf` as the content type instead of `pdf`, otherwise the attachment is added as:

```
 --b1_IUbTPYYE0RFpfwGdeVX4Ggi2ErEKTd6JwKwjRJzEtE
 Content-Type: pdf; name=attachmentpdf
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attachment.pdf
```

Instead  of:

```
 --b1_EPhqEYFUvxbgyaVbkH4eNDQXBxsXAJpRwTMMkcTY
 Content-Type: application/pdf; name=attachment.pdf
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attachment.pdf
```

The validation error is on the content type expecting a forwardslash :doh:.

```php
$mail->addStringAttachment(
    'My DOMPDF content',
    'attachment.pdf',
    PHPMailer::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'application/pdf'
);
```